# How to combine properly a scrollbar and a ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, layout

I am completely new to app development, just trying things the last 3 days and as usual, there are several things that I don't understand.

By Emulator, my vertical view does not need a scrollbar necessarily, but by **horizontal view** there are missing some of my elements and I guess needs a scrollbar. I have tried to use one, although I have have searched in internet and in stackoverflow for questions/answers relative to my problem, I had no success.

Does anyone know why i can't do something like this? Additionally, I will be glad, if there are some **general tips/practices** to optimize the code.

... and here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bground"
    tools:context=".ChargeCalculatorActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/general_linear_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="26dp"
        android:paddingRight="26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:text="@string/calculate_charge_success"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/switcher_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/normal_swiftstride"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
            android:onClick="onSwitchClicked"
            android:switchMinWidth="80dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switcher_label" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/movement_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switcher">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movement_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
                android:text="@string/unit_movement"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/movement_input"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"

                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movement_label"
                android:autofillHints=""
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/distance_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/movement_linear">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
                android:text="@string/target_distance"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movement_layout" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/distance_input"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/distance_label" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#2a9df4"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:onClick="onClickCalculate"
            android:text="@string/calculate_button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/distance_linear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/success_rate"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calculate_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="58sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/result_label" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit:
Well I found the solution. As already mention from the other guys, I had to use the the "Scrollbar". I have tried this, but there was no difference because I was "using" the wrong .xml file. A lesson for the future!
Thanks guys, you really brought a bit food for thought.

Comment: put scrollBar  in your code .then it work perfrectlly for both view (portrait and landscape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout may look different on different devices due to different screen size.
If you want to scroll horizontally you need to add HorizontalScrollView to your layout as below:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChargeCalculatorActivity">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/bground">
```

and add the closing tag `</HorizontalScrollView>` after `</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

The point to remember here is that HorizontalScrollView can have only one direct child hence it should contain only one view group like ConstraintLayout or LinearLayout.

Comment: I have applied your advice in my code (no errors at all), unfortunately I dont see any change, no horizontal scrollbar at all.

Comment: If you could share some screenshots or a small video it'll be more helpful in UI related issues!

Comment: Problem is solved. I already edited my initial post with my findings, with what was wrong. I thank you all for the advices, were all helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In general, screen resolutions and sizes differ a lot, so try to test your app as much as you can in different virtual devices. If your layout fits the screen of your current emulator is not a rule of what other users will see in their devices.

Now regarding the scrolling capability, I suggest you try and nest your root layout in a [scrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView)